# Browserify-shim with gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, shim, browserify-shim

I'm testing out gulp with browserify and I'm trying to get the following working:

I have a file called export.js, which depends on another file called export2.js.

export.js

```
module.exports = function(){ 
    console.log("test export"); 
};
```

export2.js

```
module.exports = function(){
    console.log("export 2"); 
}
```

I have another file called app.js, where I define the following code:

```
var e = require("e");
```

I tried to define the dependency by using a shim.
The related code in my package.json looks like this:

```
  "browserify-shim": { 
        "jquery": "$", 
        "public/src/js/home/export.js":  { 
            "exports": "e", 
            "depends": [ 
              "public/src/js/home/export2.js"
            ]
        }
  }, 
  "browserify": {
      "transform": [
          "browserify-shim" 
      ]
  },
```

The path should be correct.

My gulp file defines:

```
//Uglifies scripts 
gulp.task("uglify-scripts", function(){ 
    return browserify({ entries:["public/src/js/home/app.js"]})
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source("bundle.js"))  // gives streaming vinyl file object
            .pipe(buffer())             //convert from streaming to buffered vinyl file object
            .pipe(uglify())             //gulp-uglify 
            .pipe(gulp.dest("public/src/js/home/dist"))
            .pipe(livereload()); 

});
```

I tested the task before (uglification of app.js without the dependency), it runs fine.
However, with the shim defined, I still receive a message in the console mentioning

> Cannot find module 'e'

Can you see what is going wrong or what I have misunderstood?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Shims are for modules that don't support commonJS. You can simply define these dependencies explicitly:

#### export.js

```
var e2 = require('./export2.js');
module.exports = function(){ 
    console.log("test export"); 
};
```

#### export2.js

```
module.exports = function(){
    console.log("export 2"); 
};
```

#### app.js

```
var e = require('public/src/js/home/export.js');
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it works like that. I forgot that browserify is not async, so I don't need to use shim to manage the dependencies.